# Passing array to directive through ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have two problems I am facing right now.

The first problem:

I have an array containing some values and some arrays. I loop through this array with a `ng-repeat`, and send the values (including the arrays) to a directive. But when I look at what comes through at the directive's end, it is just undefined.

Here is the code:

View

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in items | filter: nameFilter">
    <analytics-table name="item.name"
                     app="item.app"
                     dates="item.date"
                     demo_cpa="item.demo_cpa"
                     bezoek_demo="item.bezoek_demo"
                     demo_trader="item.demo_trader"
                     download_bezoek="item.download_bezoek"
                     download_cpa="item.download_cpa"
                     download_demo="item.download_demo">
    </analytics-table>
</div>
```

Directive

```
app.directive('analyticsTable', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        name: '=name',
        app: '=app',
        dates: '=dates',
        demo_cpa: '=demo_cpa',
        bezoek_demo: '=bezoek_demo',
        demo_trader: '=demo_trader',
        download_bezoek: '=download_bezoek',
        download_cpa: '=download_cpa',
        download_demo: '=download_demo'
    },
    templateUrl: '../directives/analytics-table.html'
};
});
```

When I do a `console.log($scope.app)` (which is also an array) it just gives me the correct response. but when I try `console.log($scope.demo_cpa)` it give me `'undefined'`

What do I do wrong here?

And the second problem/question is:

If I get this working, is it possible to get the index value of one array, based on the loop index of another array e.g.

```
<tr ng-repeat="date in dates">
            <td>{{date}}</td>
            <td>{{download_bezoek[$index]}}</td> <-- the index of the ng-repeat
            <td>{{download_demo[$index]}}</td>   <--
            <td>{{download_cpa[$index]}}</td>    <--
            <td>{{bezoek_demo[$index]}}</td>     <--
            <td>{{demo_trader[$index]}}</td>     <--
            <td>{{demo_cpa[$index]}}</td>        <--
        </tr>
```

Comment: Try object as main item to repeat and access properties of it;

Comment: Can you show the `nameFilter` code?

Comment: Why don't use create only one attribute for your directive and pass the object as value ?

Comment: You can use `$index` if you have `ng-repeat="item in items track by $index`

Comment: @itzmukeshy7  This will give me even less of a result, nothing will show up now.

Comment: @AranS That is just a simple filter based on an input value, there is no code behind it, just an Angular filter.

Comment: Create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0):

Change your directive attribute as like as following code:

```
 <analytics-table name="item.name"
                 app="item.app"
                 dates="item.date"
                 demo-cpa="item.demo_cpa"
                 bezoek-demo="item.bezoek_demo"
                 demo-trader="item.demo_trader"
                 download-bezoek="item.download_bezoek"
                 download-cpa="item.download_cpa"
                 download-demo="item.download_demo">
</analytics-table>
```

**Directive**

```
 app.directive('analyticsTable', function() {
 return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
          name: '=name',
          app: '=app',
          dates: '=dates',
          demoCpa: '=demo_cpa',
          bezoekDemo: '=bezoek_demo',
          demoTrader: '=demo_trader',
          downloadBezoek: '=download_bezoek',
          downloadCpa: '=download_cpa',
          downloadDemo: '=download_demo'
       },
     templateUrl: '../directives/analytics-table.html'
   };
  });
```

Comment: This unfortunatly doesn't help, it still gives me an 'undefined' result

Comment: then you can write you code in **jsfiddle** or **jsBin**